# How can I update user goelocation to account record when selecting pin on map?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, geolocation

I have incorporated google map to display pins on a map for Account records. I am using `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position)` to center the map when it load and to get the users position.

When a user chooses a pin on the map and redirects to the account record, I want to populate the LAT/LNG back to the account. I am using a combination of Visualforce page and Lightning controller as shown below.

Can it be added as part of the `marker.addListener('click', function())`, which calls back to the lightning controller? Is so, how would it be incorporated?

*Visualforce page*:

```
<apex:page showHeader="false">
    <html>
        <head>
            <!-- 
                This stylesheet contains specific styles for displaying the map on this page. Replace it with your own styles as described in the documentation:
                https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial 
            -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{!$Resource.GoogleMap}"/>
        </head>
        <body>

            <div id="map"></div>
            <script>
            var lexOrigin = 'https://{!$CurrentPage.parameters.lcHost}';

            //Data for Google map
            var data;

            //Send message to LC
            function sendToLC(message) {
                if(typeof(lexOrigin) != 'undefined'){
                    parent.postMessage(message, lexOrigin);
                }
            }

            //Receive message from LC
            window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
                //If page is public (like used in force.com sites) then be careful about the origin
                //if (event.origin !== lexOrigin) {
                    // Not the expected origin: reject message!
                    //return;
                //}
                // Handle message
                console.log('Data Sent to VF: ', event.data);
                data = event.data;


                if(typeof(event.data.loadGoogleMap) != 'undefined'){
                    //Load Google Map Script
                    var script = document.createElement("script");
                    script.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&callback=initMap";
                    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);        
                }
            }, false);

            //Callback when Google Map is loaded
            function initMap() {
                //Add marker for each point along with text
                function addMarker(feature) {
                console.log('feature ===> ' + JSON.stringify(feature));

                    var markerColour;
                    var basePinUrl = "https://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_xpin_letter&chld=";
                    if(feature.pintype == "New"){
                        markerColour = basePinUrl.concat("pin|%E2%80%A2|0099ff");
                    } else if(feature.pintype == "Sale") {
                        markerColour =  basePinUrl.concat("pin|%E2%80%A2|00e600");
                    } else if(feature.pintype == "Follow-up") {
                        markerColour =  basePinUrl.concat("pin|%E2%80%A2|ff9900");
                    }else if(feature.pintype == "No Sale") {
                        markerColour = basePinUrl.concat("pin|%E2%80%A2|cc2900");
                    }else if(feature.pintype == "Appointment") {
                        markerColour = basePinUrl.concat("pin|%E2%80%A2|9933FF");
                    }else {
                        markerColour = basePinUrl.concat("pin|%E2%80%A2|cc2900");
                    }

                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: feature.position,
                        //icon: icons[feature.type].icon,
                        map: map,
                        title:feature.markerText,
                        icon:markerColour
                    });
                    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        content: feature.markerText
                    });

                    marker.addListener('click', function() {
                        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                        sendToLC({'state':'NavigateToAct', 'id':feature.id});
                    });
                }

                //Create new map
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), JSON.parse(data.mapOptions));

                 //Set map center
                infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
                if (navigator.geolocation) {
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                        var pos = {
                            lat: position.coords.latitude,
                            lng: position.coords.longitude
                        };

                      //  infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
                     //   infoWindow.setContent('Location found....you are here.');
                     //   infoWindow.open(map);
                        map.setCenter(pos);
                    });
                } else {
                    map.setCenter(data.mapOptionsCenter);
                }

                //iterate through map data for each point (even if 1)
                var mapData = data.mapData;
                for(var i=0, j=mapData.length; i<j; i++){
                    //Add marker for each point
                    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(mapData[i].lat, mapData[i].lng);
                    addMarker({position: myLatlng, markerText: mapData[i].markerText, id: mapData[i].id, pintype:mapData[i].pintype});
                }
            }

            //Let LC know that VF page been loaded along with it's URL
            //LC will then send the data
            //This is done because LC has no way to know that VF page in iFrame has been loaded, event listener set and ready for data
            var vfHost = "{!LEFT($CurrentPage.URL,FIND('/',$CurrentPage.URL,9))}";
            sendToLC({'state':'LOADED', 'vfHost': vfHost});
            </script>      
    </body>
    </html>
</apex:page>
```

GoogleMap controller:

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        //Send LC Host as parameter to VF page so VF page can send message to LC; make it all dynamic
        component.set('v.lcHost', window.location.hostname);

        //Add message listener
        window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
            //Can enable origin control for more security
          /* if (event.origin != vfOrigin) {
                console.log('Wrong Origin');
                 //Not the expected origin: Reject the message!
                return;
            }*/

            // Handle the message
            if(event.data.state == 'LOADED'){
                //Set vfHost which will be used later to send message
                component.set('v.vfHost', event.data.vfHost);

                //Send data to VF page to draw map

                helper.sendToVF(component, helper);
            }
            if(event.data.state == 'NavigateToAct'){
                console.log('account id ===> ' + event.data.id);
                var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
                urlEvent.setParams({
                    "url": '/'+event.data.id,
                    "isredirect" :false
                });
                urlEvent.fire();
            }
        }, false);
    }
})
```